# Run Cakephp3 code from cronjob

Tags: php, cron, cakephp-3.0

Hi i want execute my code from cronjob. I have used below 2 command but its not working

```
/path/bin/cake transaction chekFailedTransactions

cd /path && bin/cake transaction chekFailedTransactions
```

Where my below is my shell code

```
<?php
namespace App\Shell;
use Cake\Console\Shell;
class TransactionShell extends Shell {  
    public function main() {
        $this->out('Some MSG');
    }
    public function chekFailedTransactions() {
        //Code to execute
        $this->out('Cron Executed!!');
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: shouldn't it be TransactionShell rather than just transaction?

Comment: It's not working _how_? Are you getting errors?  Unexpected output? _Something_ must be happening.

Comment: I am setting the cron from my cpanel so not getting any error there

Comment: Take out the cron aspect and just run that command directly on the command line and see what happens.

Comment: bin/cake transation checkFailedTransactions its showing Permission denied sometime cake is not a command

Comment: Thanks @ Patrick Q . Below command working for me now                      cd /path/bin && ./cake transation checkFailedTransactions